# MacBook won't boot on Yosemite after force power off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, unibody

Macbook suddenly froze while I was using Google Chrome so I waited for 15 minutes hoping it would un-freeze. After 15 minutes, I decided to force the power off by pressing and holding the Power button. When I tried to turn it on again, I heard the chime, but the screen remained white, and the hard drive started making clicking noises.

Model identifier: MacBook6,1
OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: Try running hardware test. To do this, hold CMD+D when you hear the startup chime. A small icon of an old (around 1970s like) computer should appear in the center of the screen. Follow onscreen instructions and post any important results.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: I held CMD + D for 15 minutes (I have a good amount of patience), and I tried it twice, but I couldn't access the hardware test. Thanks for trying to help though :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The key is just D, no command key. The support link is [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11342?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: I tried holding just D, and I also tried holding Option + D, both to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Hard drive clicking/clunking/scraping noises (other than the usual sounds of an HDD in operation) are nearly always a bad thing and it's best to assume it's terminal.

If it *is* your hard disk (or if you've ever erased/replaced the disk) you won't be able to access the hardware test, in which case you will need to start your MacBook with the **Applications Install** disc that was supplied with your computer.

Comment: It's a school supplied Macbook, and when they sold the laptop to us (the students), they didn't provide the Applications Install disc. 

However, I did create a Mac OS X Yosemite installer USB. I tried to boot up the laptop using a different drive (the aforementioned USB) and I went into Disk Utility. 
My internal hard drive is no longer listed there. 

I also went into Terminal and entered 'df -hl' and it listed all sorts of things, including the USB I had plugged in, but not my internal hard drive.

Comment: What model MacBook is it? I've replaced the HDD cable on several 2012 13" MBPs here at our school following either extremely slow disk access speed or the drive completely disappearing. On a couple of machines the HDD cable needed reseating at the logic board end, otherwise a new replacement cable has restored functionality. The acid test would be to pick up a cheap external 2.5" USB drive enclosure and put your drive in it. If it works then you know the drive is ok, in which case perform an SMC reset and see if that helps, then clean the HDD connector with switch cleaner or replace the cable.

Comment: Model ID: 
MacBook6,1

Specifications: 
13" Macbook white Unibody, late 2009 model
Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.26 GHz

I've ordered an external USB drive enclosure online, and it should arrive on the 15th this month. I'll update when it arrives